# Using Two Data Iterators Under One Loop in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I would like to ask a question regarding Data Iterators in Pytorch.

I have two datasets, and would like to use a different data iterator for each of them to train one model.

To do so, I have used DataLoader for each of them to get data iterators, and shuffle argument was set to True.

Then, I have used them as following under one loop, for each epoch:

```
for idx, datum in enumerate(zip(data_iterator1, data_iterator2)):
```

Here, the length of **data_iterator1** is ~28 times longer than the length of **data_iterator2**.

Here I have the following questions in my mind:

1) When the loop ends? Does it end when the loop sees all the batches belonging to **data_iterator2**, or it ends until seeing all the batches belonging to **data_iterator1**?

2) If the loop ends after seeing all the batches belonging to **data_iterator2**, at the next epoch, are the data belonging to both data iterators shuffled again?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) When the loop ends? Does it end when the loop sees all the batches belonging to **data_iterator2**, or it ends until seeing all the batches belonging to **data_iterator1**?

Python's [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) stops when the shortest of the iterators is exhausted. `DataLoader` behaves like any other iterable. Therefore, your loop will end after all batches of `data_iterator2` have been seen.

> 2) If the loop ends after seeing all the batches belonging to **data_iterator2**, at the next epoch, are the data belonging to both data iterators shuffled again?

Yes, both are shuffled again, because the shuffling occurs when the iterator is created, which is done by the `zip()` function, assuming that `data_iterator1` and `data_iterator2` are the actual `DataLoader` objects and not iterators that have been created from them. Otherwise, it was shuffled whenever you created the iterator manually, e.g. `data_iterator1 = iter(data_loader1)`.